# How to create an EditText that goes up with the Keyboard on Android

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I have been looking on how to create something similar the Image below, I created an EditText with an ImageView with icon " Send ", but I couldn't manage on how we can create something similar to this, something that goes up with the Keyboard.

[image: Edit Text Send now]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code for such scenario-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/secondarybackground" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/messages_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/snackbar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/secondarybackground"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="normal"
        tools:listitem="@layout/message_sent" >
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/textsend"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/primarybackground" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textinput"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textSendButton"
            android:background="@color/primarybackground"
            android:ems="10"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionSend"
            android:inputType="textShortMessage|textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primarytext" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/textSendButton"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_send_now_offline" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please give the XML of this `?android:selectableItemBackground`

Comment: This attribute requires api level 11+, This is an internal attribute. see "?android:"